# Configure Docker container for spring boot micro services

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am new in docker, I want to know how to install dependency locally in maven while using docker compose yml file.

Like, I have 3 micro services and those I configured in **docker-compose.yml** file but I want one dependency to be installed in local maven using maven install so that I can use that dependency in other micro services by importing.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're describing here - are you trying to pull dependencies into your containers dynamically at runtime?  The normal Docker approach is to package up everything statically when defining an image (the "immutable infrastructure" idiom).

Comment: I also don't know what you're asking. You might look at this sample app by Docker that is a Spring Boot app: https://github.com/dockersamples/atsea-sample-shop-app There's also bee a series of blog posts about it on blog.docker.com

Comment: show us what you have until now (docker-compose.yml, Dockerfiles, etc)

Comment: Thanks for replies, I just wanted to install one dependency in maven locally before packing the other dependencies. Can I do this without doing this using Dockerfiles?